# xstream - correct way to save XML in UTF-8

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Previously, to **read** XML in UTF-8 encoding through xstream, I am using DomDriver as follow :

```
XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF-8"));
```

However, later I realize this is VERY slow. I use the following way :

[Optimize loading speed of xstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623546/optimize-loading-speed-of-xstream)

This works fine at least.

However, later, I realize the same technique cannot be applied to write XML. I will get all ??? characters.

This is the last workable code using DomDriver during **write**

```
public static boolean toXML(Object object, File file) {
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF-8"));
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        xStream.toXML(object, outputStream);
    }
    catch (Exception exp) {
        log.error(null, exp);
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        if (false == close(outputStream)) {
            return false;
        }
        outputStream = null;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The above code works fine. In order to match with the **read** method which doesn't use DomDriver, I change the code to

```
public static boolean toXML(Object object, File file) {
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    Writer writer = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        xStream.toXML(object, outputStream);
    }
    catch (Exception exp) {
        log.error(null, exp);
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        if (false == close(writer)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (false == close(outputStream)) {
            return false;
        }
        writer = null;
        outputStream = null;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This time, all my Chinese characters changes to ???

May I know anything I had done wrong?

Comment: Hi - What are you passing as 'object' in the above method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
xStream.toXML(object, outputStream);
```

You're *creating* a writer which will use UTF-8 - but then completely ignoring it!

Try this instead:

```
xStream.toXML(object, writer);
```

Also as a matter of style, I'd encourage you to consider the following:

- Don't compare results with Boolean constants; just use `if (foo)` or `if (!foo)` instead
- Catching `Exception` is *very* rarely a good idea; catch specific exceptions instead
- Returning a Boolean value to indicate success or failure isn't idiomatic Java; generally if something fails, an exception is better
- If the first `close` fails, you're quitting the method before the second `close` call, which probably isn't what you want. (In fact, closing the OutputStreamWriter` will close the stream anyway, but consider the principle of the thing.)
- Setting local variables to `null` at the end of a method is unnecessary and clutters up your code

Comment: @Jon Oh my GOD! You have a sharp eye!

Comment: I think there is additional mistake, I should not return in finally block. Instead, I should use boolean status = close(writer); status = status & close(outputStream);... and return the status just at the very end of the method.

Comment: @Yan: Returning from a finally block is okay, so long as you're careful. In particular, returning from the *end* of a finally block is fine. You just don't want to miss out some of your cleanup code due to returning half way through it.

Comment: @Yan: More importantly though - does the change to use `writer` in the `toXML` call work for you? :)

Comment: Yes. toXML works. Regarding your comment on finally, have you seen this before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java

Comment: @Yan: Hmm... no, I wasn't aware of that. Yikes indeed. That's somewhat surprising.